# stuck at memoizing dynamic programming code

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to get Maximum numbers of elements that their sum is less than or equal some variable but i don't know how i can memoize it and call the funcition from main()so that it passes the allowed time in codeforces any clarifications about the memozing and calling the function process
here is [link of the problem](http://codeforces.com/contest/279/problem/B), 
and here is my recursive function:

```
int n,initial_time;

int books[1000001];
vector < vector<int> >MEMO(10000,vector<int>(10000,-1));

int estimateTime(int i,int reminder,int previousElement){
  if(i==n)
    return 0;
  if(MEMO[books[i]][previousElement]!=-1)
    return MEMO[books[i]][previousElement];
  int choise1=estimateTime(i+1,reminder,previousElement);
  int choise2=0;
  if(books[i]<=reminder)
    choise2=1+estimateTime(i+1,reminder-books[i],books[i]);

  return MEMO[books[i]][previousElement]=max(choise1,choise2);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the problem is; "stuck" doesn't give much to go on.

Comment: Why you allocate books on the stack?

Comment: so that i can use it in the function scope or from everywhere i want.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
using namespace std;
#define ll long long
#define cti const int
#define ctll const long long
#define dg(i) cout << '*' << i << endl;

typedef pair<int, int> p;
cti N = 100001;
int n, t;
int a[N];
vector<p> v;

bool cmp(const p& a, const p& b){return a.second < b.second;}

int main()
{
    int i, j;
    while(scanf("%d %d", &n, &t) != EOF)
    {
        v.clear();
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) scanf("%d", a + i);
        if(n == 1)
        {
            if(t >= a[0]) puts("1");
            else puts("0");
            continue;
        }
        int k;
        int sum;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if(!i)
            {
                k = 0;
                sum = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                if(sum) sum -= a[i-1];
            }
            for(j = k; j < n; j++)
            {
                if(t >= sum + a[j])
                {
                    sum += a[j];
                }
                else
                {
                    k = j == i ? k + 1 : j;  
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(j == n)
            {
                v.push_back(make_pair(sum, n - i));
                break;
            }
            if(j - i) v.push_back(make_pair(sum, j - i));
        }
        if(v.empty()) puts("0");
        else
        {
            sort(v.begin(), v.end(), cmp);
            printf("%d\n", (v.end()-1)->second);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it is another way to solve the problem i'm not sure if that what i asked for
i can solve it with another 2 ways but i want to sharpen myself at the dp zone so i'm trying to solve it dynamically and i'm asking about ways of memozing and calling it :)